# I can't present something after the userDidEarn function of RewardedView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, alert, uialertcontroller

I'm using AdMob rewarded ads on my application. I want to present an alert after user watched an advertisement. I tried it but It doesn't work. I can't see the alert after the user closes the rewarded advertisement.

```
func rewardedAd(_ rewardedAd: GADRewardedAd, userDidEarn reward: GADAdReward) {
    rewardedAdService.reloadRewardedAd()
    rewardedAdService.rewardedAdIsWatched { (newMoney) in
        trainingStartView.coinShowView.number = newMoney
        showAlert(title: "You got rich ", message: "You've earned 30 Coins!!!")
    }
}
```

Here is the show alert function:

```
func showAlert(title:String = "Oops!",message:String = "Something went wrong"){
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: _"It doesn't work"_, this is something you need to be much more specific about in your question

Comment: Yes, you are right. I edited.